# Line break in Label

Tags: asp.net, html, css

when i m writing a long sentence in label without line break then it does wrap automatically.
i m putting that label in  tag. how can i wrap that long sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create style sheet like this "

```
.label { word-wrap: break-word }
```

and assign to you label

check the link for more detail  : http://www.css3.com/css-word-break/

Comment: What is break- word?Explain it.

Comment: check the link posted in ans for more detail

Comment: Not familiar with ASP.NET, but since it uses the main framework still, can't you use the word-wrap property of the control? Or, set the control to be a multi-line label (Might be thinking of TextBox here...). Either way, WordWrap property should work too?

Answer (score 7):

Unclear, but you can force a line break by adding a `<br />` in it.

```
<label>Some long long long long long long<br /> long long long label</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd hesitate to use the CSS3 solution without some kind of IE fallback.

You need to add the following CSS to your label:

```
label { display: block; width: 100px; }
```

Then change the width to the width you'd like your label to be and the sentence will wrap within the space.

By default a label has inline display which makes width control difficult.

If you still need the label to be inline with your input field, float the label.