# Display label text with line breaks in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to display the label text with line breaks exactly as per the image

[image]

I need the text on the label to be printed exactly can some one help me, my desired text that has to be shown on the label will be stored in a string-builder

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You may append HTML `<br />` in between your lines. Something like:

```
MyLabel.Text = "SomeText asdfa asd fas df asdf" + "<br />" + "Some more text";
```

With **StringBuilder** you can try:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Some text with line one");
sb.AppendLine("Some mpre text with line two");
MyLabel.Text = sb.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `MyLabel.Text = "Hey!"+"\n"+" hey!"`? :D

Comment: I don't think this works in this context, though it may work in other contexts.  Nor does "\r\n" work in this context.

Answer (score 12):

I know this thread is old, but...

If you're using html encoding (like [AntiXSS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss(v=vs.110).aspx)), the previous answers will not work. The break tags will be rendered as text, rather than applying a carriage return. You can wrap your asp label in a pre tag, and it will display with whatever line breaks are set from the code behind.

**Example:**

```
<pre style="width:600px;white-space:pre-wrap;"><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Runat="server" visible ="true"/></pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `<br/>` where you want to break the text.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `<br />` for Line Breaks, and `&nbsp;` for white space.

```
string s = "First line <br /> Second line";
```

Output:

```
First line
Second line
```

For more info refer to this: [Line break in Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915983/line-break-in-label)

Comment: Really good answer.  I would just add that \r\n (which usually work in most contexts) does not work in this context, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use the following

```
@"Italian naval...<br><br>"+
```

Above code you can achieve double space. If you want single one means you simply use
.

Answer (score 3):

I had to replace new lines with br

```
string newString = oldString.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

or if you use xml

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ShowLineBreaks(Eval("Comments")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Then in code behind

```
public string ShowLineBreaks(object text)
{
    return (text.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br/>"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or simply add one line of:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Comments").ToString().Replace("\n","<br />") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following line worked for me:

```
lbTabRes.Text += num + " x " + i + " = " + (num * i).ToString() + "<br/> \n";
```