# Retrieving data from Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

I want retrieve data from oracle database, below is my code,
My sql query has 4 results how can i retrieve 4 result in my label.

### Code

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(
"Data Source=10.127.240.216/ipcldb;User ID=ipcltos;Password=ipcltos;Unicode=True");   
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
"select Initcap(ZZFNAME) ZZFNAME 
from sap_empmst where substr(GBDAT,1,6) = substr(sysdate,1,6) 
and stat2 =3 and werks in('RIGC','IPGC') and plans<99999999 order by persk", con);      
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();     
// int i;
//   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
Label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
con.Dispose();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: With 4 results you mean 4 rows? Which data you get from this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice to use a Label to show more than one row info is not a good choice. I would suggest to use a ListBox or Combobox or a Multiline TextBox or event a Grid. (all controls that are built to show more than one item)

But your code has other problems.

Here how I would write it (still using a single label)

```
string cmdText = @"select Initcap(ZZFNAME) ZZFNAME 
                   from sap_empmst 
                   where substr(GBDAT,1,6) = substr(sysdate,1,6) and stat2 =3 
                         and werks in('RIGC','IPGC') 
                         and plans<99999999 
                   order by persk";
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(.....))
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while(dr.Read())
          Label1.Text += dr.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

The fix for the single label problem is to build a loop around the reader using the boolean return value of dr.Read() call. Then using  += to concatenate the current record value to the previous content of the label

Another important change  revolves around the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) that ensure the proper closing and disposing of the connection, command and reader also in case of exceptions

Comment: Thank you so much....one question if i want break the line after showing one result in same label how can i do it?

Comment: Add a `<br />` after the GetString(). IE `dr.GetString(0) + <br />` but the label should be made taller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878347/display-label-text-with-line-breaks-in-c-sharp