# How to display new lines in label control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label control to which I am binding text property. My text contains new lines but when I am displaying the data it is showing it in one new line.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server"></asp:Label>

lblText.Text = xml.Value;
```

My xml.Value contains the below mentioned text.

```
For ex:
```

My text is :

```
Hi!
How are you??
```

After binding it is showing as

```
Hi! How are you??
```

But I want to display as

```
Hi!
How are you??
```

Can the label display such text in new lines with `\n` or `br`.

Comment: Where are you displaying the data?

Comment: On the page @Oluwafemi

Answer (score 1):

Check the textwrap property  and the use multiline property of the label

Comment: I tried textwrap properties but none are giving the required output. Does label has a multiline property? I know textbox has. @Mudassir

Comment: If not I'm sure you can try adding the text as "Hi \n how are you"

Answer (score -1):

Just add a `<br/>` in your comment. You can do a replace of \n as well

You can use `lblText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />");` after binding

[Display label text with line breaks in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878347/display-label-text-with-line-breaks-in-c-sharp)

or before binding.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server"></asp:Label>

lblText.Text = xml.Value.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: This is about .Net control not javascript. Read the tags before you answer.