# ASP.NET Web Forms, Something equivalent or similar like a Console for Text on a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm moving over a simple text manipulator program in C# to ASP.NET Web Forms.

I have found that "asp:Label"s can be changed from the code behind, I can't find a list of other "asp:?things?" to use like textbox or textarea etc. I have tried but they are not valid for asp.

Trying to do multiple lines for a Label I don't think is possible. So is there another "asp:" that can act like a console or show multiple lines? Or can you do multiple lines with a Label?

WebPage.aspx

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="Label1"></asp:Label>
```

CodeBehind for WebPage.aspx

```
Label1.Text = ("My text I wanto change or add etc.");
```

**My problem:**
My C# code requires adding multiple lines, I don't think this can be done with Labels it will only show the last output in the array.

```
protected void ShowRawData(string[] rawData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; ++i)
        // Console.WriteLine(rawData[i])
        Label1.Text = (rawData[i]);
}
```

How can I show all the lines in the array with ASP.NET and Web Forms?

Comment: This post should help you with Labels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878347/display-label-text-with-line-breaks-in-c-sharp. ASP.NET also has TextBoxes and they can accept multiple lines of text (with `TextMode="MultiLine"`).

Comment: FYI you do not need to add a beginning `(` or an ending `)` in this line `Label1.Text = (rawData[i]);`

Comment: You could just as easily use a simple div and line-breaks without incurring the overhead and random HTML generated by the out-of-the-box controls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Textbox with these properties set:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" ></asp:TextBox>
```

For showing all lines of the array:

```
protected void ShowRawData(string[] rawData)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; ++i)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(rawData[i]);
    }
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```